# How to use nodemon to watch a folder being deleted and added back with new files?

Tags: nodemon

I have an app that generate **build** folder after building. Each time, the app will delete the whole **build** folder and add it back with new files inside.

I try to watch this folder change and do something.

```
nodemon --watch build --exec doSomething
```

However, this command will only watch if the **build** folder exists all the time and the file changes inside. It does not work when the whole folder got deleted and added back.

How to use `nodemon` to watch a folder got deleted and added back with new files with new files inside? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At least on MacOS, if the `-L` or `--legacy-watch` flags are used, `nodemon` stops working after the watched directory is deleted and fails to work correctly until the `nodemon` process is killed.

If the `-L` or `--legacy-watch` flags are omitted, `nodemon` works correctly after the watched directory is recreated.